# Javascript Compiler Error in Google Tag Manager: Parse error. primary expression expected

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm getting the error message:

> 'Error at line 146, character 2: Parse error. primary expression expected'

For the following code on line 146, the final line of my CustomHTML tag, any idea what's going on?

GTM tag:
[image: GTM tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your information, you have written javascript code inside a `<style>` tag according to the screen shot you have provided here. Javascript code always goes between `<script></script>` tags or inside a separate js file.